# Keep only groups where all values satisfy a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to make a `df.groupby` and keep only those rows that have negative values in a column for all the rows in the group.

For example, I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Lucas','Marie','Lucy','Lucas','Marie','Lucas','Phil','Marie','Marie','Lucy','Lucas']})
df['rand'] = np.random.randint(-5, 2, df.shape[0])
df
    name    rand
0   Lucas   -1
1   Marie   -5
2   Lucy    -4
3   Lucas   -2
4   Marie   -1
5   Lucas   -3
6   Phil    0
7   Marie   1
8   Marie   -4
9   Lucy    0
10  Lucas   -1
```

I am trying to `df.groupby('name')` and keep only those names whose all values in `df['rand']<0`. In this case, I would just keep 'Lucas' since it is the only name that has all negative values in the column 'rand'.

My aimed output, then, is:

```
    name    rand
0   Lucas   -1
3   Lucas   -2
5   Lucas   -3
10  Lucas   -1
```

Normally I would do `df= df[df['rand']<0]`, but logically it won't do the job here.

How can I do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check first which are bellow `0`, then group the boolean series by `df['name']` and transform with `all`. Then use the result to index the dataframe:

```
df[df.rand.lt(0).groupby(df.name).transform('all')]

     name  rand
0   Lucas    -1
3   Lucas    -2
5   Lucas    -3
10  Lucas    -1
```

---

General procedure to simplify similar cases:

- Apply condition to be fulfilled to end up with boolean column/s
- [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) grouping column in original dataframe
- [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with `all` (or `any`). We want `transform` since it keeps the original size
- Use the result to perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) on df